# Is there a limit for php form textarea/message?

Tags: php, forms

I have a simple php form which contains fields to, subject and message. Whenever i type message longer than 316 chars in message(textarea), the form unable to send it. its like the message return blank. For less than 316 chars it is working fine. I've set post_max_size to 64M in php.ini but still not working. There is no error log.

I've tested this form in a few different hosts. Only one host is showing such behavior. Some hosts require to increase post_max_size to make it work. How to solve this issue? Any help much appreciated.

Comment: The two limiting factors are config value that you mentioned and possibly a max body size directive on the webserver itself. 316 is a very small value to be flaking out on because of size ... more likely it has something to do with the content of what you are posting as opposed to it's size. Are you properly escaping the data that you are inserting?

Comment: @Orangepill the form just send straight away to email, not storing into any db. do i still need to proper escape the data? the same data was working fine on the other hosting.

Comment: That shouldn't cause any code breaks then. Check into the webservers max post body limit that will supersede anything set in the php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved after changing form method from GET to POST. Hope this help someone else.